# How to overcome a missing reference/library in VBA using Access/ADOB connection?

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access, database-connection

I have an 'excel front end' for an access database. The idea is that 10 users have their own spreadsheet which can query the database for items relating to them and then they can also respond and write back the database via a macro.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub update_access()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
    "Data Source=S:\Public\XYZ\XYZ\XYZ\XYZ\XYZ.mdb;"
' open a recordset
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "qryXYZ", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

g = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row


For f = 3 To g

If Cells(f, 11) <> "" Then
        lnId = Cells(f, 1)
        rst.Filter = "ID = " & lnId
    With rst
        .Fields("response") = Cells(f, 11)
        .Update
    End With
        Cells(f, 11).ClearContents
End If

Next f

wb.RefreshAll
MsgBox ("All finished!")
End Sub
```

It worked perfectly on my own PC whilst I was testing it, however when sending it to the users they all received the same 'project or library not found/missing'
On further investigation and reading I found a post regarding Missing libraries, in my case: `Missing: Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library` . Not sure where to go from here, does this mean the users need to have access installed on their PC's to have access to the library or could a copy of my GUID/reference be copied over into their Program Files (x86) (same location as where my reference is)

Starting to get into a realm where I don't want to tread as this would likely mean asking IT department to do that, can anyone think of an alternative solution?

In addition to that I have had to resort to saving the database as `.mdb` instead of `.accdb`as `"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _` does anyone know the correct connection type/provider to enable me to access an `.accdb` as I feel like I've cheated by resorting to an older version of access in order to make my code work?

Comment: Try adding a reference to 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library'. I am not sure if it is installed only if Access is installed, but it may be possible. If this works, you can also try late binding. I mean, declare the variables as `Dim cn As Object, rst As  Object` and then set it as `Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")`.

Comment: You don't need the Access reference for the code you posted, so try just unchecking it and saving the workbook. Then see if the code still works.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot Rory - you're right that reference isn't needed.